# Android program crashes when using getAssets()

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, assets, typeface

I have a class MyActivity which extends activity. This class is essentially present only to hold a few extra methods that I will need and it also holds the typeface that i will be using for the entire app. So, for instance, I have an activity "HomeScreen" that extends MyActivity. However, when I try to instantiate the typeface using:

```
    lavi = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Lavi.ttf");
```

the program crashes due to a nullpointer that seems to be occurring at the getAssets() method. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix the problem?

EDIT:
Logcat:

03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{android.PhysicsEngine4/android.PhysicsEngine4.HomeScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:74)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.PhysicsEngine4.MyActivity.(MyActivity.java:19)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.PhysicsEngine4.HomeScreen.(HomeScreen.java:12)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
03-07 23:47:16.389: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9432):     ... 11 more

Comment: Can you please post your logcat data

Comment: sure, it will be there in a minute

Comment: Try this   lavi = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/Lavi.ttf");

Answer (score 0):

HI,

plz check font name case (capitalized characters) Lavi.ttf or lavi.ttf and try to use same in code as you have put in assets folder.

Comment: it is Lavi.ttf in the fonts folder. Thanks though.

Comment: put this font inside ur assets folder and run

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the conflicting Android API in the module's AndroidManifest.xml file  and project's AndroidManifest.xml. make sure them stay the same if you have the file in modules.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mrwujay.cascade"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <application/>
</manifest>
```